# Any way for a FORTRAN main program to return a value to the OS?

Tags: unix, return-value, fortran90

Apologies if this has been asked.  I have done alot of looking around before typing.  In any event: Is there any way that a FORTRAN main program can return a value to the operating system.  I am thinking something like

```
if (some error) then
  stop(1)
elseif (some other error) then
  stop(2)
endif
```

which of course is bad code, but I hope I am getting across what I want to do.  BTW, I am not looking for output to STDOUT, but for a value returned to the OS.  Thanks.

And, in my particular case, I am running PGI and gfortran on a Linux system.

Comment: Which implementation of fortran are you using? GNU's one, or another?

Comment: @paxdiablo I am currently running PGI and would like something portable to gfortran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard recommends that a numeric stop code be made available as the operating system's process exit status, if these concepts are relevant for the Fortran processor.  Example syntax is simply:

```
STOP 2
```

This is only a recommendation in the standard, not a requirement, but I'd expect most Fortran compilers to do the sane thing.

Comment: OK, tried it.  It works with gfortran.  Surprisingly for me, it does not work with PGI.  PGI echoes a '2' (or whatever) to STDOUT, but returns a value of 0, regardless.  I was testing originally with PGI, expecting that, if anything, gfortran would have less capability.  Guess I've learned something.  Anyone know what to do with PGI?

Comment: @bob.sacamento Actually, I have found that the Portland Group's compiler follows the Fortran 90 standard very closely and does not implement many (if at all) non-standard features.  gfortran, on the other hand, has many non-standard features. You can expect gfortran to have more capability than most other compilers, and Portland Group's to have less.

Answer (score 2):

For `gfortran`, you can use the [`EXIT`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.3/gfortran/EXIT.html) subroutine::

```
CALL EXIT(2)
```

This may not be portable for other compilers, though.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me while STOP 2 did not.  I used Lahey Fujitsu Fortran 95 v5.7.